# ngRepeat not displaying elements

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using Angular for a project, but the ngRepeat doesn't seem to be working. Here's the code:

HTML code:

```
<ion-content>
<ul class="list">
    <li ng-repeat="r in res" class="item">
      <h2>{{r.name}}</h2>
      <p>{{r.locality}}</p
    </li>
</ul>
</ion-content>
```

JS code:

```
 var user = $state.params.user;
 var whereClause = "agent_email = '" + user.email + "'";
 var queryBuilder = Backendless.DataQueryBuilder.create().setWhereClause( whereClause );
 Backendless.Data.of("Hotels").find( queryBuilder )
.then(function(foundHotels) {
  $scope.res = foundHotels;
  console.log($scope.res);
  console.log($scope.res[0].name);
  console.log($scope.res[1].name);
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log("error" + error.message);
})
```

Backendless is returning an array with all the values. It returns the correct values in the console, but the ng-repeat part isn't working. I inspected the element on Chrome, and the ng-repeat part is getting converted to this: `<!-- ngRepeat: r in res -->`. What is going wrong?

Example of console.log(res):

```
[DataStore.model]
 0: DataStore.model
 agent_email: "a@b.com"
 amenities: "example"
 city: "bangalore"
 name: "jw marriott"
 // other parameters
 1: DataStore.model
 agent_email: "a@b.com"
 amenities: "example"
 city: "bangalore"
 name: "fairfield marriott"
 //other parameters
length: 2
```

Comment: Add an example of the response in the question.

Comment: this mostly happens when `ng-repeat` can't find `scope` variable, make sure you have included the controller.

Comment: Try update your $scope bindings with `$scope.$apply()`

Comment: Couple of this you should check. 'res' should be an array and since its being populated asynchronously you should refresh the binding as well.

Comment: Please initialize an array as $scope.res = [ ]

Answer (score 0):

You are missing either controller or app that's why it's commenting out. It will comment out in only one situation when your object is empty.Check your ng- controller and ng-app first.

Comment: Both seem to be fine.